# Rotate list for every letter in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a Caesar cipher that changes the key each letter, I currently have a working cipher that scrambles the entire string once, running 1-25 however I would like it to do it for each letter, as in the string "ABC" would shift A by 1, B by 2 and C by 3, resulting in BDF

I already have a working cipher, and am just not sure how to have it change each letter.

```
    upper = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase)
    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    upper.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)
    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)

    upper = ''.join(list(upper))
    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper)).translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))
#print (caesar("This is simple", 2))
our_string = "ABC"


for i in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)):
    print (i, "|", caesar(our_string, i))
```

Outcome is this:

```
0 | ABC
1 | ZAB
2 | YZA
3 | XYZ
4 | WXY
5 | VWX
6 | UVW
7 | TUV
8 | STU
9 | RST
10 | QRS
11 | PQR
12 | OPQ
13 | NOP
14 | MNO
15 | LMN
16 | KLM
17 | JKL
18 | IJK
19 | HIJ
20 | GHI
21 | FGH
22 | EFG
23 | DEF
24 | CDE
25 | BCD
```

What I would like is to have it a shift of 1 or 0 for the first letter, then 2 for the second, and so on.

Comment: Have you used list comprehension before? I recommend writing a function that given an index and a character rotates the character by that amount (look at the mod operator, ord, chr). Then, use a list comprehension while iterating over the enumerate of the plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good effort! Note that the mapping doesn't only rearrange letters in the alphabet, so it's never achieved by rotating the alphabet. In your example, upper would become the following mapping:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BDFHJLNPRTVXZBDFHJLNPRTVXZ
```

Also note this cipher is not easily reversible, i.e. it's not clear whether to reverse 'B'->'A' or 'B'->'N'.

(Side note: If we treat letters ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY as numbers 0-25, this cipher multiplies by two (in modulo 26): `(x*2)%26`. If instead of 2, we multiply by any number not divisible by 2 and 13, the resulting cipher will always be reversible. Can you see why? Hints: [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).)

---

When you feel confused about a piece of code, often it's a good sign it's time to refactor a part of it into a separate function, e.g. like this:

(Playground: https://ideone.com/wNSADR)

```
import string


def letter_index(letter):
    """Determines the position of the given letter in the English alphabet

    'a' -> 0
    'A' -> 0
    'z' -> 25
    """
    if letter not in string.ascii_letters:
        raise ValueError("The argument must be an English letter")

    if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        return ord(letter) - ord('a')
    return ord(letter) - ord('A')


def caesar(s):
    """Ciphers the string s by shifting 'A'->'B', 'B'->'D', 'C'->'E', etc

    The shift is cyclic, i.e. 'A' comes after 'Z'.
    """
    ret = ""
    for letter in s:
        index = letter_index(letter)
        new_index = 2*index + 1
        if new_index >= len(string.ascii_lowercase):
            # The letter is shifted farther than 'Z'
            new_index %= len(string.ascii_lowercase)
        new_letter = chr(ord(letter) - index + new_index)
        ret += new_letter

    return ret


print('caesar("ABC"):', caesar("ABC"))
print('caesar("abc"):', caesar("abc"))
print('caesar("XYZ"):', caesar("XYZ"))
```

Output:

```
caesar("ABC"): BDF
caesar("abc"): bdf
caesar("XYZ"): VXZ
```

---

Resources:

- [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)
- [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)